# Read each character of argument in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

sample input in cmd:

```
test.bat /p 1,3,4
```

expected result:

```
1
3
4
```

my codes so far:

```
@echo off
set arg = %1
set var = %2
if (%1)==(/p) (
... need code that will read and print each character of var
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="/p" (
:LOOP
echo %2
shift
set arg=%2
if defined arg goto :LOOP else exit >nul
)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a potential problem with your question. If test.bat is:

```
@echo %1%
```

Then

```
test 1,2,3
```

Prints:

```
1
```

Because, in this context, the comma is treated as an argument delimiter.

So you either need to enclose in quotes:

```
test "1,2,3"
```

Or use a different internal delimiter:

```
test 1:2:3
```

Unless you want the parts to be placed in %2, %3, etc., in which case you problem is solved by a trivial use of `SHIFT`.

For my solution I have elected to require quotes around the group parameter, "1,2,3" (though this is easily adapted for a different delimiter by changing `delims=,` to specify the character you want to use).

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set args=%~2

if "%1"=="/p" (
:NextToken
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%f in ('!args!') do (
        echo %%f
        set args=%%g
    )
    if defined args goto NextToken
)
```

Call like:

```
readch.bat /p "1,2,3"
```

`%~2` is used to remove the quotes.

The `FOR` statement parses args, puts the first token in `%f` and the remainder of the line in `%g`.

The `goto NextToken' line loops until there are no more tokens.

Answer (score 1):

```
set params=%%~2
if (%1)==(/p) (
    set params=%params:,= %
)
if "%params%" NEQ "" (
  call :printer %params%
)
goto :eof

:printer
:shifting
if "%%1" NEQ "" (
  echo %%1
) else (
 goto :eof
)
shift
goto :shifting
goto :eof
```